# How to secure Android Manifest and string xml using Proguard

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, proguard, reverse-engineering

I tried using proguard to protect the code from reverse engineering below is my code. But still, all my resource files are not obfuscated.

```
# debugging stack traces.
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-dontwarn com.alldaydr.clinician.ui.auth.model.*

#rules for custom view
-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

#Keep Native codes
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { native <methods>; }

#keep model class
-keepclassmembers class com.alldaydr.clinician.ui.auth.model.* { *; }

# OkHttp3
-keep class okhttp3.* { *; }
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**

#Retrofit 2
-keep class retrofit2.* { *; }
-dontwarn retrofit2.*

what all things I should include in the above code for protecting the code from reverse engineering.
```